# Django. Проблема с выводом ошибки при неверно введенных данных в поле формы

Tags: django

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. При вводе неверных данных текст ошибки выводится в неверном формате, перепробовал уже кучу всего, ничего не помогает. На картинке ниже видно в чем проблема.

[image: Некорректное отображение ошибки]

В forms.py прописываю функцию check_if_there_are_any_repeats_of_unique_fields(), которая должна менять текст ошибки, но при запуске она как будто не отрабатывает. Может кто знает в чем может быть дело?

views.py

```
def building_form(request, id = 0):  # insert operation
    if request.method == "GET":
        if id == 0:
            form = BuildingsForm(initial={'id': buildings_id_autofill()})
        else:
            building = Buildings.objects.get(pk=id)
            form = BuildingsForm(instance=building)
        return render(request, "database/buildings/buildings_form.html", {'form': form})
    else:
        if id == 0:
            form = BuildingsForm(request.POST)
        else:
            building = Buildings.objects.get(pk=id)
            form = BuildingsForm(request.POST, instance=building)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            building_name = form.cleaned_data.get('building_name')
            messages.success(request, 'Здание с именем "' + building_name + '" было успешно добавлено в базу данных.')
        else:
            # errors = form.errors
            # print(errors)
            return render(request, "database/buildings/buildings_form.html", {'form': form}) 
        return redirect('/add_new_building/')
```

filters.py

```
class BuildingFilter(df.FilterSet):
    name = df.CharFilter(field_name='building_name', label='Имя здания', lookup_expr='icontains')
    descr = df.CharFilter(field_name='description', label='Примечание', lookup_expr='icontains')
    coords = df.CharFilter(field_name='coordinates', label='Координаты', lookup_expr='icontains')
    addr = df.CharFilter(field_name='address', label='Адрес', lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Buildings
        fields = ['name', 'facility_id', 'coords', 'addr', 'descr']
```

models.py

```
class Buildings(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=4, primary_key=True, blank=True)
    building_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    facility_id = models.ForeignKey(Facilities, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coordinates = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["building_name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.building_name
```

forms.py

```
class BuildingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Buildings
        fields = '__all__' #['building_name', 'facility_id', 'coordinates', 'address', 'description']
        labels = {
            'id': 'Уникальный идентификатор',
            'building_name': 'Имя здания',
            'facility_id': 'Название предприятия',
            'coordinates': 'Координаты здания (опционально)',
            'address': 'Адрес здания (опционально)',
            'description': 'Комментарий (опционально)',
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BuildingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['facility_id'].empty_label = "Выберите предприятие..."
        self.fields['id'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = "Пример (eng): B1337"
        self.fields['id'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()# скрываем поле id для пользователя
        self.fields['building_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = "Пример: стр.1337"
        self.fields['coordinates'].required = False
        self.fields['address'].required = False
        self.fields['description'].required = False

    def check_if_there_are_any_repeats_of_unique_fields(self):
        # b = Buildings.objects.all()
        building_name = self.cleaned_data.get('building_name')
        for instance in Buildings.objects.all():
            if building_name in instance:
                # Здесь также пробовал строку "raise forms.ValidateError..." Также не сработало 
                self.add_error('building_name', "Имя '" + building_name + "'уже есть в базе данных. Введите другое имя.")
        return building_name
```

html.html

```
{% extends "database/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% include 'https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/' %}
{% block title %}Добавление в БД{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="boss col-md-10 offset-md-2">
        <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-6 font-weight-bold align-center mt-n3">Добавление нового здания в БД</h1>
  <hr class="my-4">
        <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="fff">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            {{ form.errors }}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <p id="messages" style="text-align: center; color: darkgreen; font-size: x-large; font-weight: bold">
                    {{ message }}
                </p>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg"><i class="fas fa-folder-plus"></i> Добавить в БД</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-n3">
                    <a href="{% url 'building_table' %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-lg">
                       <i class="fa fa-stream"></i> К таблице Здания
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Для того, что бы названия полей отображались правильно и в label и в списке ошибок не забывай добавлять `verbose_name` для полей в описании модели
       `building_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, verbose_name="Имя здания")`
2. Ты написал функцию, которая проверяет на уникальность, но не видно, что бы ты где-то пытался ее вызвать.
3. По большому счету тебе не нужна это функция, потому, что у тебя в описании поля стоит `unique=True` и django автоматически будет проверять это поле на уникальность
4. Если хочешь изменить сообщение об ошибке, когда имя здания не уникально можно сделать так

```
    class BuildingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
        ...
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(BuildingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            ...
            self.fields['building_name'].error_messages = {
                'unique': "Выбранное имя здания уже используется, выберите другое имя",
            }
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, теперь все отображается как надо :)